# why is Separating my code into Static Library have much code size than within the main in C in terms of .bin or .out file or an executable?

Tags: c, linker, static-libraries, compiler-optimization, code-size

I had a code inside the "main" that could be detached into a static library, so I separated this part into a new static library folder and included it with my main script.

as follows I had the example with a no-library version

```
#include "XXX_lib/XXX_Core.h"

void main(){
 /* list of code that uses some functions from XXX_lib/XXX_Core.h library 
  * which is been found inside the main project as a sub folder and 
  * I included the main header file from this folder
*/
}
```

and the project tree was like

```
|-Main_Project_foler
|--- main.c
|--- XXX_LIB -> (folder)
|-------XXX_Core.h
|-------XXX_Core.c
|-------XXX_OS.h
|-------XXX_OS.c
|-------XXX_Patterns.h
|-------XXX_Patterns.c
|------- .....
```

afterward, I separated the **XXX_lib** files into a static library and generate an **XXX_lib.lib** file that I can use along with my main code as a static library and I can reuse it with other modules in my project so the project structure was like

```
|-STATIC_LIBRARY_XXX_folder
|--- Debug ->(folder)
|-------XXX_LIB.lib
|--- XXX_LIB -> (folder)
|-------XXX_Core.h
|-------XXX_Core.c
|-------XXX_OS.h
|-------XXX_OS.c
|-------XXX_Patterns.h
|-------XXX_Patterns.c
|------- .....
|
|-Main_Project_folder
|--- main.c
```

and I included the absolute path of my **XXX_Lib** directory for the compiler and the **.lib** file to the linker search path and the compiler is **TI Arm C/C++ Compiler Version 18.12.5.LTS** and the code are running on a 32-bit MCU ( TM4C129 ) and options passed to the compiler have many include paths so excluding them with ${manyIncludePaths} arg the flags are

`-mv7M4 --code_state=16 --float_support=FPv4SPD16 -me -Ooff --opt_for_speed=2 ${manyIncludePaths}  --define=PART_TM4C129XNCZAD --define=ccs --define=TIVAWARE --define=ccs="ccs" -g --gcc --diag_warning=225 --diag_wrap=off --display_error_number --gen_func_subsections=on --enum_type=packed --abi=eabi`

and the linker flags are

`-m"${ProjName}.map" --heap_size=0 --stack_size=512 -i"${INHERITED_LIBRARY_PATH}" -i"C:/ti/wolfssl/tirtos/packages/ti/net/wolfssl/lib" -i"${CG_TOOL_ROOT}/lib" -i"${CG_TOOL_ROOT}/include" --priority --reread_libs --diag_wrap=off --display_error_number --warn_sections --xml_link_info="${ProjName}_linkInfo.xml" --rom_model`

these are the default linker flags and I added `--lto` and noticed that the code size is reduced in both cases no-library and library versions.

after that, I noticed the final .out file generated by the compiler increased by twice the static library size with optimization set to level 2 for Static Library and main code

I checked the map file in both versions(no-library and with library versions) and found that my module in the library version had a file (XXX_Patterns.c) that had taken much size than usual (I mean than no-library version), so from this comparison, I noticed that this file had many **static structures** with **#pragma** allocating them to static SRAM cause my MCU  has an EPI peripheral, so I used external memory (SRAM),

**XXX_Patterns.c** file is like

```
#pragma DATA_SECTION(objColor1, ".xram3");
static XXX_ColorType objColor1[XX_MAX_NUMBER];

#pragma DATA_SECTION(objColor2, ".xram3");
static XXX_ColorType2 objColor2;


static INT32U                 u32Count;
static INT32U                 u32MaxLoops;

static void XXX_func1(void);
static void XXX_func2(void);
...
```

so, How to eliminate that size difference between the no-library and library versions because the two examples I mentioned have the same functionality(the one with the library separated and the one that is not-separated)?

Comment: Is link time optimization on? (if your linker supports that)

Comment: I'd guess it stopped it from inlining, and inlining with constant args had let it optimize down to much simpler code.  Or it does still inline, but also a stand-alone version isn't getting removed?  Without a [mcve] or any details on what compiler name/version/options you used, all we can do is guess.  Blocking link-time optimization is quite likely, if your static library didn't contain LTO object files.

Comment: I am using TI Arm C/C++ Compiler Version 18.12.5.LTS and the code are running on a 32-bit MCU ( TM4C129 ) and options passed to the compiler have many include paths so excluding them with ${manyIncludePaths} arg the flags are 
`-mv7M4 --code_state=16 --float_support=FPv4SPD16 -me -Ooff --opt_for_speed=2 ${manyIncludePaths}  --define=PART_TM4C129XNCZAD --define=ccs --define=TIVAWARE --define=ccs="ccs" -g --gcc --diag_warning=225 --diag_wrap=off --display_error_number --gen_func_subsections=on --enum_type=packed --abi=eabi `

Comment: and actually, I am using the "XXX.lib" file generated from Static library compilation to build the main code's executable, also, 

I enabled the LTO for linking the separate example with "-lto" flag (main code) but got an error with the linking process as it is unrecognizable and enabled optimization lvl=2 for static library compilation but I still have the same result of having much space difference between the example with a separated library and the one without a separated library

Comment: the linker flags are `-m"${ProjName}.map" --heap_size=0 --stack_size=512 -i"${INHERITED_LIBRARY_PATH}" -i"C:/ti/wolfssl/tirtos/packages/ti/net/wolfssl/lib" -i"${CG_TOOL_ROOT}/lib" -i"${CG_TOOL_ROOT}/include" --priority --reread_libs --diag_wrap=off --display_error_number --warn_sections --xml_link_info="${ProjName}_linkInfo.xml" --rom_model `

but it is been created by default from my IDE which is CCS by the way.

Comment: [edit] your question with that further info, so you can put the code in code blocks.  Also, that's still not a very clear description of whether LTO is working for the no-library version, or a [mcve].  I'd suggest looking in the binary with a disassembler or `readelf -a` or similar tools to see which section has the extra size, and if there are extra symbols.  Or if the extra size is metadata.

Comment: last night I enabled  LTO with the flag `--lto` to the linker command and still have that difference and after checking the .map file generated by the compiler I notice that this difference is related to static functions that is never been called in the main function or any derived modules so why linker included them while there is no reference to them, also why they hadn't been included by the linker in the no-library version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem was in compiler flags as it needs to separate each subsection of functions into a separate block obj so while the ".out" is generated it should link only the used sections in the main object file that is going to be linked so as you can see in the image below just enable this option and the code size would be the same as no-library version.

[image]